# How to do this glare in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to duplicate the glare behind this girl in Photoshop.

[image: Glare]

How can it be done? Alternatively, is there a tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-u-0No0nwH4) you go

> There are a number of ways to create glare in Photoshop, add a lens flare under the "Filter" section and set the direction of the flare. Find out how to use a "wind blur" to create glare in Photoshop with help from a graphic and Web designer in this free video on Photoshop.